# How can I conditionally use next/image component on React library?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a library that's used in multiple websites. One of these runs on Next JS, and I want to use the component next/image to all the images on the website, without affecting the other websites that don't use NextJS. For that I have to conditionally change the existing Image component on the library and switch to next/image, so all the component that use Image use now next/image. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Please see [ask] and provide some example code for context.

Comment: I actually understood what you mean. I don't think there is a way to detect if your library is running on a NextJS server. I guess you could make a variable that you would set in different types of servers. If you can show some code and the structure of what you are doing I might be able to help you find a way.

Comment: Also, is your library running on the server side or client side. Remember that this is very important to know if you are using NextJS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters, you need to do something like this:

Define your own `Image` component somewhere (that uses `next/image` if available) and use it everywhere you were using `img`:

```js
// utils/image.js

import React from "react";

const Image = ({ src, ...props }) => {
  try {
    return React.createElement(require.resolve("next/image").default, {
      src: typeof src === "string" ? src : src.src,
      ...props
    });
  } catch {
    console.log("Not using Next.js");
    return React.createElement("img", { src, ...props });
  }
};

export default Image;
```

Usage will be same in both CRA and Next.js:

```js
// example component

import Image from "../utils/image";
import bg from "../assets/bg.jpg";

const Foo = () => <Image src={bg} height="640" width="959" />;

export default Foo;
```

Here are CodeSandboxes: [CRA](https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-solomon-7jith), [Next.js](https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-mountain-6x03j)

---

Now to make this robust you need to properly modify your custom `Image` component. I am listing some of the things that need to be taken care of:

- `next/image` adds wrapper `span`s, while normal `img` won't do something like that. So to keep the UI consistent across frameworks. Wrap `img` the same way Next.js does for you.
- `img` tags can be created without height and width, while `next/image` components cannot be (unless you are using static import), you can test this thing by checking if the `src` is an object.
- Check for the things that are different between Next.js Image component and simple `img` element. See if a difference has anything to do with the use cases of your library. If so, then try to bridge the gap between `next/image` and `img`. Obviously you need to fix only layout stuff, if you wanted both to be exactly the same you won't be using different in the first place.
- After fixing your component, use only features that are supported both by `next/image` and your custom `img` component.

Comment: When its used on server side component, `(require.resolve('next/image') as any).default` will return me type `undefined`. Besides, how to do it if i want to implement the library on client side component? Please help